# Unable to remove phantom iTunes storage under the new mac storage management tool

Tags: macos

The storage tool, opened from *About This Mac*, shows there is 30.15GB of iTunes data. I went into the iTunes root folder and removed all the music and podcasts. The 30.15GB remains. I have tried restarting the mac. Is this a bug or is there somewhere else I should look to delete this 30.15GB of data?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Be patient. It takes some time for the Mac to rebuild the index that determines the (exact) size of each section.

Keep a mobile Mac connected to a power source if you want to accelerate the process.

You could also rebuild the spotlight cache, but it's barely worth it just to update the view.

Comment: Thanks but it has been 4 days. The iTunes storage stays at 30.15GB.

Comment: @VictorYip have you tried doing a spotlight re-index before?

Comment: I find this link on how to do the re-indexing 

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

But I am not sure if I should just uncheck and recheck the items under "search result" or manually add them to the privacy tab and remove them to trigger the indexing.